# Altering the URI value that all subsequent RewriteRule's use to match against

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have a production and development server that are clones of each other.
I also have an apache24 reverse proxy server that is handling all incomming
requests and proxying content from different back end servers based on the URI.

I want the proxy to pull the content from our development server if the URI
starts with '/test', eg: https://ourdomain.com/test/some/app/index.php?foo=bar

However, I don't want to have to create duplicate rules for everything,  one for
production and one for test so I am trying to figure out how to acomplish this
with a single rule for each of the rewrite rules that pull in content from a
backend server

I have figured everything out except how to effectively remove the '/test'
portion from the URI (if it's there) that RewriteCond, RewriteRule, and
<Location ..> all use to match against.

The end result that I am looking for is:

Incomming request of https://ourdomain.com/some/app/index.php?foo=bar the proxy server does this:

```
RewriteRule ^/some$ /some/ [R=301,L]
<Location "/some/">
ProxyPass            https://BackendProductionHost/some/app/index.php?foo=bar
ProxyPassReverse    https://BackendProductionHost/some/app/index.php?foo=bar
</Location>
```

Incomming request of https://ourdomain.com/test/some/app/index.php?foo=bar the proxy server does this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/some$ /test/some/ [R=301,L]
<Location "/test/some/">
ProxyPass            https://BackendDevelopmentHost/some/app/index.php?foo=bar
ProxyPassReverse    https://BackendDevelopmentHost/some/app/index.php?foo=bar
## Note that '/test' is NOT part of the URI sent to the backend development server
</Location>
```

But using just ONE set of rules to handle both situations.

Why?  We have a lot of different backend servers and each of those have a
development clone.  I am trying to reduce the duplication of rules.

The following is what I have:

```
## fyi - These are located in a <VirtaulHost> .. and not a .htaccess, if it matters


RewriteEngine On
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On

## Set an environment variable named 'serverhost' to the production server
## host value (BackendProductionHost)
##    Note:
##      -- I have to use 'SetEnvIfExpr' because "The SetEnv directive runs
##         late during request processing meaning that directives such as
##         SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables set with it."
##      -- The expression "1==1" always evaluates to true which allows me
##         to set a default value.    

SetEnvIfExpr "1==1" serverhost=BackendProductionHost


## Change the 'serverhost' env value to the development server host value
## If the URI begins with a path of '/test', eg:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test
RewriteRule .* - [E=serverhost:BackendDevelopmentHost]


## Remove /test from the URI      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test
#RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ $1 [E=REQUEST_URI:$1]
##   -- Neither of the above change the URI value that RewriteCond, RewriteRule,
##      and <Location ..> use for their matching,  IS THIS POSSIBLE?


## If the URI used for the matching can be changed to remove '/test' when it
## is present then the following would work:


RewriteRule ^/some$ /some/ [R=301,L]
<Location /some/>
    ProxyPass            https://${serverhost}/some/app/ interpolate
    ProxyPassReverse    https://${serverhost}/some/app/ interpolate
</Location>
##  The rules above only work for the production URL and never the test URL
##  (no request sent to BackendDevelopmentServer)

## I have also tried the following:
ProxyPassMatch  "^(/test)?/some/"  https://${serverhost}/some/app/ interpolate

## The rule above works for the production URL and at least generates a
## request to the back end development server but the request from the proxy
## to the dev server looks like:
## "GET /some/app//test/some/index.php?foo=bar HTTP/1.1"
```

### Is what I am trying to do possible or should I just stick to having a duplicate set of rules for test ??

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to acheive what I was asking.  In a nutshell, the configuration below allows us to browse production websites as usual and browse to it's development counterpart by adding '/test' after the domain portion of the URL.

For example:

https://our_public_domain.example/somewebstuff/thing.htm

and

https://our_public_domain.example/test/somewebstuff/thing.htm

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# - We are creating some environement variables and assigning default values
# - pertaining to a production environment.  If the URI begins with '/test/'
# - then we are overwriting the environment variables with variables
# - pertaining to a test environment.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------


# - set default environment variables to production values
# - Note that the 'test' variable is set to nothing
SetEnvIfExpr "1==1" lnxhost=192.168.1.1
SetEnvIfExpr "1==1" winhost=prodserver.example
SetEnvIfExpr "1==1" apihost=another.example/some/production/enpoint/base
SetEnvIfExpr "1==1" test=


# - override environment variable values to development values if URI matches: ^/test/
# - phrased differently, if the request was *not* ^/test/, skip these next four rules aka: [S=4]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=4]
RewriteRule .* - [E=lnxhost:192.168.1.100]
RewriteRule .* - [E=winhost:devserver.example]
RewriteRule .* - [E=apihost:another.example/some/development/enpoint/base]
RewriteRule .* - [E=test:/test]


# /somewebstuff is proxied to the lnxhost backend server 
RewriteRule ^(/test)?/somewebstuff$ $1/somewebstuff/ [R=301,L]
ProxyPassMatch  "^(?:/test)?/somewebstuff/(.*)$"  "https://${lnxhost}/somewebstuff/$1" interpolate
<LocationMatch "(/test)?/somewebstuff/">
    ProxyPassReverse    https://${lnxhost}${test}/somewebstuff/ interpolate
</LocationMatch>
RewriteRule ^(/test)?/somewebstuff/ "-" [L]


# /someapistuff is proxied to the apihost backend server
RewriteRule ^(/test)?/someapistuff$ $1/someapistuff/ [R=301,L]
ProxyPassMatch  "^(?:/test)?/someapistuff/(.*)$"  "https://${apihost}/$1" interpolate
# Note: ProxyPassReverse is not needed for the someapistuff API usage
RewriteRule ^(/test)?/someapistuff/ "-" [L]


# anything not handled by a rule above is proxied by default to the winhost backend server
ProxyPassMatch  "^(?:/test)?/(.*)$"  "https://${winhost}/$1" interpolate
<LocationMatch "(/test)?/">
    ProxyPassReverse    https://${winhost}${test}/ interpolate
</LocationMatch>
```

I've also inclulded a heavily commented explanation of the syntax I am using:

```
# - Any URI's that are exactly 'example' or 'test/example' (without a trailing slash)
# - are redirected to 'example/' or 'test/example/' (with a trailing slash)
# - The 'L' flag stops any further rule prosessing
#RewriteRule ^(/test)?/example$ $1/example/ [R=301,L]

# - Content is retrieved from the backend content location for URI's that
# - begin with 'example/' or 'test/example/':
#ProxyPassMatch  "^(?:/test)?/example/(.*)$"  "https://${lnxhost}/backend/content/$1" interpolate

# - The locationMatch and ProxyPassReverse allow for proper proxy handling of redirects
# - sent from the backend server in both a test and production context:
#<LocationMatch "(/test)?/example/">
#    ProxyPassReverse    https://${lnxhost}${test}/backend/content/ interpolate
#</LocationMatch>

# - Stop any further processing of rules
#RewriteRule ^(/test)?/example/ "-" [L]
```